# How to detect if the Wear app of my Android app is already installed in the watch

Tags: android, wear-os

Is it somehow possible to detect if the Wear mini app inside an Android app is already installed in the watch?

I have an app which cannot be used on the phone until the Wear part is installed in the watch, so I want to block all interaction until then.

What about app updates, is it possible to detect if the Wear part was already updated?

**EDIT:**

It looks like the Data API and even Message API calls are buffered and delivered after the app is installed. This however does not solve the issue with app updates. That is solvable with the accepted answer.

Comment: One solution would be to write something to data layer from the watch when it's installed. Although for me it sounds like XY problem - what are you trying to solve exactly? Why your app can't run without wearable app?

Comment: How can a Wear app do something automatically after it is installed? In my case the Wear part has no `Activity` it is a tool. The phone app sends just commands and settings via the MessageAPI and DataAPI. I do not want to loose the DataAPI calls for syncing settings and I do not want to pull the data from the DataAPI in the Wear app all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no out-of-the-box solution to do it.

If your Wear app does not have activities (and therefore no means to be started by user), what you can do is send something like `IS_INSTALLED` message to Wear periodically while handheld app is in foreground until Wear won't put it version number into data layer. On application update you can check for version number in data layer and if it's lower than current version - repeat the procedure.

This approach will as well solve problem with Wear device not being connected (or out-of-range which is essentially the same).

Comment: this looks like the best method. will implement this and will let you know.

Comment: @shelll if you'll find better alternatives - please let us know as well

Comment: this works good. i send a "/version" message to the watch every few seconds and the watch sends back the version code set in the `build.gradle`/`AndroidManifest.xml`. both the phone and wear app must have the same version code (otherwise the app will not work) so if i get back a different value the app is installed but not yet updated. if i do not get an answer within few seconds then the app is not yet installed.

Comment: @DmitryZaytsev what if our app contains activity? then how to check app install on wearable or not and vice versa?

Answer (score 3):

One Solution is to use CapabilityClient(https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/CapabilityClient). First you can detect whether the Wearable and phone are connected or not using NodeClient(https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeClient). Below I have mentioned the code to detect whether the watch is connected to phone or not in android.

```
    Task<List<Node>> nodesTask = Wearable.getNodeClient(MainMobileActivity.this)
            .getConnectedNodes();
    nodesTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Node>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Node> nodes) {
            nodeSize = nodes.size();
            for (Node node : nodes) {
                Wearable.getMessageClient(MainMobileActivity.this)
                        .sendMessage(node.getId(), MESSAGE_PATH, "Hello from AndroidWear".getBytes());
            }

            Log.d("Hello" , "Message sent to Cordova");
        }
    });
```

So, nodeSize tells how many nodes/watches are connected.

```
Wearable.getMessageClient(MainMobileActivity.this)
                        .sendMessage(node.getId(), MESSAGE_PATH, "Hello from AndroidWear".getBytes());
```

This piece of code helps to send the message from phone to watch. Now coming to detect whether the watch has the application or not. Below is the mentioned code for it.

```
    Task<CapabilityInfo> capabilityTask = Wearable.getCapabilityClient(this)
            .getCapability(CAPABILITY_WEAR_APP, CapabilityClient.FILTER_REACHABLE);
    capabilityTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<CapabilityInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CapabilityInfo capabilityInfo) {
            mWearNodesWithApp = capabilityInfo.getNodes();

        }
    });
```

So, if mWearNodesWithApp comes as 0 it shows that app is not installed and if it shows 1 it means application is installed.

CAPABILITY_WEAR_APP should be of String type and should have the value which you mentioned in wear.xml of wear application and not of phone. Do remember to mention the same applicationId for both Phone and Wear application.